# How to disable css in safari

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari

I've got an annoying issue where `safari iOS` does not scroll to the focused input on a page. How can I disable the css in safari for testing purposes (iphone 6 emulator)?

Develop -> Disable Styles does not do the trick for the emulator.

Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

Me too faced same issue, then i moved to [browserstack](http://browserstack.com) , which gives accurate results